# Cannot use RDP on Azure VM after installing Kaspersky Endpoint Security

Tags: remote-desktop, powershell, firewall, azure, kaspersky

I have a Windows VM hosted in Azure where i have many websites (IIS) and yesterday i installed Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 SP1 to be secure. Everything went normal during the process and after it finished and autostarted, like you may gessed, the firewall blocked me.

I managed to have access to the server using powershell but nothing worked:

- msiexec /x {7A4192A1-84C4-4E90-A31B-B4847CA8E23A} /qn (there is a process - msiexec - but avp is still alive)
- avp.com stop firewall (Error: Command unavailable due to password protection disabled)
- trying to stop the AVP service

If anybody have a suggestion i'll be more than grateful. As for now, the websites are OK but better now than later.

Comment: I would just roll back to the snapshot I created of the Virtual Machine before the software was installed.

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't make a snapshot before the operation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try to removing the Kaspersky by WMIC.

Tpye "product get name" to get the name of the installed Kaspersky.

Then use "product where name=”name of program” call uninstall" to remove the Kaspersky.

Here is a good [article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/272460-programs-uninstall-using-command-prompt-windows.html) about how to use WMIC to uninstall the packages on Windows.

If it still doesn't work, please check if Kaspersky has been removed successfully. And also, please check if the Windows firewall has been modified. If yes, just use PowerShell command to add an inbound rule to allow TCP 3389.

Comment: i tried "DISM /online /get-packages" but it shows only windows packages not installed apps

Comment: The suggested command isn't applicable to the software that should be removed

Comment: @etshei You're correct. Sorry about the misleading information, I've updated my answer. Also, this method has been verified in my lab.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reminding and I have updated my answer.

Comment: @StevenLee Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm.
the command `Get-WmiObject Win32_Product` gets the packages
i used `$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Name = 'Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 for Windows'"`
then `$app.Uninstall()` to uninstall